# Styling bootstrap card header is not working

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

```
Rails 5.2
Bootstrap
```

I have the folliwing style:

```
.app-card-header {
  .card-header:first-child {
    background-color: white;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-color: green;
  }
}
```

That I am trying to apply to this view:

```
.app-card-header
  .card
    .card-header
      = 'This is a test header'
    .card-text
      = 'This is test text'
```

However, I am not getting the results I'm expecting.

The header background color is white, and the header text alignment is right, but the font color is black and the size looks about 12.

I tried different font sizes and colors to no avail, but it's not changing. Why would parts of the styling work, and other parts not? Any ideas?

Comment: Its seems like the css class you have provided here doesn't match with the css class defined in your HTML. Can you please post you HTML output?

Comment: @SantoshAryal No, the scss class I am using matches, that's not the issue. This is Rails and .slim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just use `color` but not `font-color`:

```
color: green;
```

And if this still doesn't work for you, then your element could be overridden from other rules. You may simply try adding important rule:

```
font-size: 16px !important;
color: green;
```

Comment: color: white; worked. Is font-color deprecated? font-size is working now as well

Comment: I have not used font-color anytime before. So, I don't know if it was added in css anytime.